# Firebase/Admob - failed to load ad, error code 0

Tags: android, firebase, admob

Trying to setup Admob connected to Firebase in Java Android using Android Studio. After app tries to fetch an ad I get:
"There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0"

I am using

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-4659004653816xxx~xxxxxxxxxx");
```

Also using:

```
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putBoolean("is_designed_for_families", true);

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) // Emulator
        .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
        .addKeyword("parent")
        .addKeyword("child")
        .build();

    mAdView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdView.bringToFront();
```

XML contains:

and in the xml layout

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-465900465381xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

My build.gradle's are:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kissta.obfusiated"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you just create the Ad Unit ID? It can take a few hours before the it starts delivering ads.

Comment: remove `.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)` for release and have you kept `google-services.json` in your app module

Comment: Very old Ad Unit ID (Years), yes

Comment: I added the sha-1 which I skipped and added the new google-services.json file again and now am getting error code 3 instead of 0.